# Cron error old_api while running Schedule Action odoo 8

Tags: cron, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have created a function which is working fine if i use it through the view. but it's not working on schedule action, in openerp log show the following error.

```
TypeError: old_api() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

My module

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):
_name = 'account.invoice'
_rec_name = 'invoice_number'

@api.multi
def create_invoice(self):
    id = self.id
    amount = 0
    journal = self.env['journal.entry']
    for credit in self.invoice_line:
        fee = credit.amount * credit.qty
        if credit.account.parent.type.name == "Revenue":
            journal.sudo().create({'account': credit.account.id,
                                 'credit': fee,
                                 'student_id' : self.student_id.id})
```

Comment: show all error log and your model `journal.entry`

Answer (score 3):

For method to work as a scheduled action you should call it with @api.model decorator instead of @api.multi, which works with view buttons.